# Spring data mongodb pageable

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I´m trying to make it works pagination with spring data mongodb, but I found that the first imt eworks, but if I increase the page number in the pagination return me always 0 records.
Here´s my code:

The code in my Service

```
 @Override
    public List<Purchase> findByUserId(String userId, int pageNumber) {
        Pageable request =
                new PageRequest(pageNumber - 1, PAGE_SIZE);
        return purchaseRepository.findByUserId(userId, request).getContent();
    }
```

And here the repository

```
@Component
public interface PurchaseRepository extends MongoRepository<Purchase, Integer> {

    Purchase findById(@Param("id") String id);

    Page<Purchase> findByUserId(@Param("userId") String userId,Pageable pageable);

    List<Purchase> findAll();


}
```

But like I said, when pageNumber is 1 everything is ok. But when is 10 the second time the result is 0
PAGE_SIZE = 10 and yes, I already check the database and I already have 15 documents.

Any idea fellas?

Comment: Just checking - do you have 15 documents for the userId you are searching with? The first time when it works - what is the value of getTotalElements()?  Second time pageNumber should be 2 right, why is it 10?

Comment: omg!, so stupid I just realize that pageNumber is 1,2,3,4 I thought that I should send 1, 10, 20 if page_size was 10.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 15 documents, with pageSize=10, you will only have data in page# 0 and 1 containing 10 and 5 elements respectively. Subsequent pages should fetch you no objects